# Table Pagination of large data using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, pagination

I am developing an application where table will be created dynamically from list using `<c:foreach>`.  Some times data will be around 12000 .I have used so many pagination plugins

```
footable.paginate.js  
jquery.ingrid.js  
pagination.js
```

but it is taking more time and browser is crashing.
Please suggest me with good table pagination plugin

Answer (score 3):

I used DATATABLE PLUGIN in my application. It provide pagination and sorting of coloumns.
This may help you http://datatables.net/

Comment: Thanks @parth.hirpara .It is working fine for below 5000 records after that for some times script is not responding.